# X- Ray diffraction confusion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, x-ray-crystallography

In X-Ray diffraction experiment how the reflected rays superimpose as we know reflected rays are parallel. As we can see in the image
[image]

Comment: They aren’t parallel. That’s an approximation (more than decent one).

Comment: Please can you describe broadly